# How to create clone of database programatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

I want to create clone of database programatically. My requirement is, I have a default master template of database,  I want to create a new database when my application will execute and this new database will be copy of existing master database, just its name will be changed.

Comment: Can you prepare a backup of the master database and use a script to restore it under a different name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to create a backup of the master database and restore it under a different name using a script:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [CopyOfMaster] FROM  
DISK = N'C:\Temp\Master.bak' 
WITH  FILE = 1,  
MOVE N'Master' TO N'C:\Temp\copy.mdf',  
MOVE N'Master_log' TO N'C:\Temp\copy_log.ldf',  
NOUNLOAD
GO
```

Explanation of parameters:

- `DISK` - path and file of your backup file
- `MOVE` - you need one line for each file group in the original database. You specify new file name and path for each file group

More reading on [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx)

Comment: When I use above command, it gives me some error as
1. TestDB.mdf cannot be overwritten.  It is being used by database 'TestDB'
2. TestDB.mdf. Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file.

While I restore database manually, it restores successfully but when I store with above command, it gives error.

Comment: Ok, I'll fix that for you tomorrow, sorry, can't do it at the moment.

Comment: Thanks @szymon. 
I think, issue is in mdf and ldf file. When we execute the command, old defalut master template mdf and ldf file exist there, so it dont allow to restore database. If you have any solution of this problem, plz share

Answer (score 0):

You need to script your master template database and save the script to a file. Use SQL Server Management Studio, right click on your master template database and select 'script database as'. You will have to change the database name in the script to some identifier which you can perform a string replace to change the name at runtime.

In your code you can load the script file and execute to create your database with a different name. You can make use of the SqlCommand to execute the loaded script (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx)

You can also make use of the command line 'sqlcmd' utility or SQL Server Management Object(SMO). Although I have not explored any of those options.

Comment: I dont want to use scripts because db size is very heavy, If I do, there will be many numbers of line of code. Can we implement this via db backup(.bak) file